# Is there any library for html validation in C/C++?

Tags: c++, html, c, html-parsing

I'm writing a code that accepts a HTML page, does some modification to it and then shows it on the web.

My requirement would be to validate this HTML code before processing it.

What should I do ??

Comment: Validate against? Most HTML in the world violates at least a few rules.

Comment: All I want is to do a basic validation. Like, if there are any open HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a library for validation, but I know the W3C validator has an API (http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html), so if you're in an online environment you can talk to it via SOAP.

Or, since it's open source, you can install your own copy and use that.

HTML validation is horribly complicated, so I doubt there are many options here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the WDG HTML Validator.
A web page on the source code is at: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/source.html.en